# Error when calling function to sort array of n numbers

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, selection-sort, function-definition

I am trying to write a function by the name of `selection_sort`. This function should, when presented with an array of n integers, search the array to find the largest element then move it to the last position of the array. Once it has done this it should call itself recursively to sort the first n-1 elements of the array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selection_sort(int [], int);

int main(void)
{
  int n, a[n];
  printf("How many numbers do you wish to sort? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Well go on, type them in... "); 
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

  selection_sort(a, n); 

  printf("Here is the sorted array: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  printf("\n");

 return 0;
}

void selection_sort(int a[], int n)
{
  if(n == 1) return;
  
  int temp, largest = 0;
  
  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] > a[largest])  
      largest = i;
  }

  temp = a[largest];
  a[largest] = a[n-1];
  a[n-1] = temp; 
   
  selection_sort(a, n-1);
}
```

When I run this code I get segmentation fault: 11. It doesn't look like any part of my code is going out of the boundaries of the array. I understand that an array of length n is indexed from 0 to n-1. What is going on?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: I don't have one, is it common practice to use one?

Comment: You'll spend 50% of your engineering life staring at one, scratching your head, and trying to understand what just went wrong, so.. yeah, it's common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This declaration of an array

```
int n, a[n];
```

has undefined behavior because the variable `n` used as the size of an array is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

You need at first to assign a positive value to the variable `n` and only after that to declare the array `a`.

```
int n;
 
printf("How many numbers do you wish to sort? ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int a[n];
```

Also your function can invoke undefined behavior if the user will pass a non-positive value as the second argument due to this condition

```
if(n == 1) return;
```

Change it the following way

```
if(n < 2) return;
```

You could make your function more "recursive" if to write an auxiliary recursive function that searches the largest element in an array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t max_element( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 ) return 0;
    
    size_t i1 = max_element( a, n / 2 );
    size_t i2 = n / 2 + max_element( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 );
    
    return a[i1] < a[i2] ? i2 : i1;
}

void selection_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        size_t largest = max_element( a, n );
        
        if ( largest != n-1 )
        {
            int tmp = a[n-1];
            a[n-1] = a[largest];
            a[largest] = tmp;
        }
        
        selection_sort( a, n - 1 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;
    
    do
    {
        printf( "How many numbers do you wish to sort (enter a positive number)?  "  );
    } while ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n < 1 );
    
    int a[n];
    
    printf( "Well go on, type them in... " ); 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", a + i );
    }
    
    selection_sort( a, n ); 

    printf( "Here is the sorted array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }       
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
How many numbers do you wish to sort (enter a positive number)?  10
Well go on, type them in... 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Here is the sorted array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, you write

```
 int n, a[n];
```

when `n` has indeterminate value.

In other words, `n` is of a type which can have trap representation, does not have it's address taken, is a locally scoped automatic storage variable and not initialized - thereby having an indeterminate value. While using that as the array size will most definitely create issues.

To avoid this, you can make use of `n` after you have successfully taken the value from user and assigned it to `n`. Pseudocode would look like

```
integer n = 0;

if ( scan_from_user_and_check_success (&n) ) //function returns 0 in failure
{
    array a[n];

    // use `a[n]`

}
```

Comment: Agh.  Just say n is not initialized.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Added that one. But only not initializaton is not the issue, there's more as I tried explaining.

Comment: I see, so I should place the ```int a[n]``` expression after the first call of scanf to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Guthrie: No.  If you want the array to be the same size as what the user entered, you will have to malloc it.

Comment: malloc has not yet been covered in the textbook I'm going through, is there not a solution that doesn't include malloc?

Comment: Make your array larger than any number of numbers that might be entered in the assignment;

Comment: say, `int a[100];`

Comment: @RobertHarvey *"If you want the array to be the same size as what the user entered, you will have to malloc it."* - Um... *what* ? A VLA can absolutely do what the OP wants. it just needs to be declared after `n` is determinate to the desired size. I don't recommend them because they're a stack blowout waiting to happen, but still.

Comment: @PalLaden That works in C++, not so much in C.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Even more to my confusion why you said what you said. The OP doesn't have to `malloc` anything, in no small part because its not even on the options block yet.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I missed that c tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We never really were. I just didn't get (and still don't) why you said, "If you want the array to be the same size as what the user entered, you will have to malloc it." That's all I'm saying. (literally).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not to be stubborn but placing ```int a[n]``` after the first scanf did work. Surely it does then create an array of the exact length that we need (that is of length n)? Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Guthrie `n` is a runtime value.  `int a[n]` is a compile-time concept; `n` would have to be resolved at compile time for that to work.

Comment: Also this is not a school assignment, I'm teaching myself how to code from books... Hence why I might seem totally clueless!

Comment: @Guthrie VLAs are a feature of C, but they're inherently dangerous because the tend to dig potentially too deep into a generally finite resource: automatic storage (commonly called "stack space"). Ex: run your program and enter `2147483647` for `n`. Now think about where your program is going to put an automatic-storage 2gB array, especially in a scenario where that storage pool is *considerably* smaller than that. VLAs only have two upsides: they're very fast, and they're self-garbage collected (scope = life), but those come with a price.

Comment: @WhozCraig Great explanation, yes I am aware that such a value for n would far exceed how C would store an integer on my computer. I appreciate the heads up about the perils of VLAs. Feel free to recommend any good books/articles about C or computers. I wonder how users here got so knowledgable, hard work and time I suppose.

Comment: @Guthrie ridiculous amounts of both (three decades and counting).

Comment: Well that makes me feel a little better! I have yet to experience three decades of anything :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
int n, a[n];
```

You are trying to dynamically allocate an array of integers with size `n`. At compile time, `n` has indeterminate value. Unfortunately you did not allocate anything. You have only declared an array that has no allocation.

Please read [this article](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html) about dynamic allocation.

Comment: `At compile time, n has no value.` better to say, indeterminate value.

Answer (score 1):

[Sourav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284030/error-when-calling-function-to-sort-array-of-n-numbers-in-c/67284059#67284059) is correct. However, I've took the liberty to make some modifications to your code so as to follow good programming practices.

The selection_sort prototype missed the int array name.

```
void selection_sort(int a[], int);
```

Varibale n was no initialized (but that was not the problem here)

```
int n = 0;
```

The array declaration should be included after the n input (this was the problem)*.

```
printf("How many numbers do you wish to sort? ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int a[n];
```

Finally, you are not considering the empty array case in your slection_sort function.

- Although declaring variables at the beginning of a funtion is a good programming practice, in this example you can't get away with it because you are getting the array size from standard input. In a second approach to this problem you should try and use dinamically allocated memory for the int array. However, if you're new to C or to solving this kind of problem, this program is just fine.